# Devise gem & custom constroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a controller I created for Devise that I want to use to add a few more pages inside /devise/registration/

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :detect_account_ended

  def import
    @title = "Import customers from Quickbooks"
  end

  def categories
    @title = "Edit Categories"
    @categories = current_user.categories

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @categories }
    end
  end

  protected

    def after_update_path_for(resource)
      edit_user_registration_path
    end
end
```

I created the routes

```
  devise_for :users, 
    :path_names => { 
      :sign_up => "register", 
      :destroy => "logout" },
    :controllers => { 
      :registrations => :registrations } do
        get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
        get '/users/import' => 'devise/registrations#import'
        get '/users/categories' => 'devise/registrations#categories'
  end
```

And the views.  The views show up correctly but the objects I pass from the registrations controller are not going to the views.  How do I fix this so that these objects are getting passed to my views?

Comment: I think your controller name should be a string: `:registrations => 'registrations'`

Answer (score 0):

Try access them directly into view like this:

```
current_user.categories
```

As `current_user` is available in views too, as for the @title, you don't have to pass it as a variable, as you can add the text you need directly into view too.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.  Do you happen to know when it isn't being passed from the controller though?

Comment: Did you try to evaluate the variables ? dose @title.nil? return true ?

Comment: Yes, in my view I have `<% if @categories.nil? %>  None <% else %> List them code  <% end %>`  and None will show up which is good, except for the fact that if I go into the console and type `User.find(25).categories` (of which 25 is my user id), I'll get a list of Categories, so I know they're there...